# Maven eclipse: project configuration is not up to date with pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I was just wondering if any of you have a tip to avoid getting the eclipse error:

project configuration is not up to date with pom.xml each time you switch branch with different pom files.
This is really annoying and I know just selecting it and doing quick fix or doing maven update solve it but it is a lost of time each time.

Thanks ;).

Comment: There is an experimental option in the m2e preferences to automatically update projects.

Comment: Nice I will try that hoping it works well :)

Comment: Even though the refresh of eclipse is taking a while this option fixed the issue thanks ;) Wish I could select your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental option in the m2e preferences to automatically update projects.

Answer (score -1):

Dose refresh the file and turn the auto build works? I think this cause the cache of the m2e plugins. It treats the file change, when you switch the branch.It should refresh the cache, so you must manual do it as your said.

Answer (score -1):

Please press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hold it down. Then press <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: This does not help without an explanation what this key combinations do. Furthermore, it seems to be just a variant of a Maven Update.